# What are the words spoken at the start of "I'll Do the Talking Tonight" song (Russian language)?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

The Bollywood Movie [Agent Vinod (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1395025/) has a song named [I'll do the talking tonight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBwHbik0ILk).

The song starts with some Russian lines. I searched everywhere in the internet but I didn't find a single article or website explaining the meaning of those Russian lines.

If anybody in this forum knows, please listen to the song if you haven't and explain. It's been a mystery since 2012. :D

Listen to this song online [here](https://gaana.com/song/ill-do-the-talking-tonight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lyrics are in Serbian, not Russian. These lines come from the song "Ruse kose curo imaš":

> *Serbian text*:
>   Aman, da gi žalim,
>   ne bi ti gi dala
>   da gi mrsiš ti!
>
> *Translation (by [lyricstranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/ruse-kose-curo-ima%C5%A1-girl-you-have-mahogany-hair.html))*
>   Even if I did,
>   I wouldn't give them to you
>   To play with them

You can listen to the song itself, performed by Gordana Lazarević, on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Erp_TTeVmM

Comment: I was looking for since the day it came. Just curiosity. How did you find it?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma well, I instantly recognized that it's not Russian. Then I asssumed that it's Slavic, tried typing out lyrics to Google, and after multiple attempts kind of got lucky :)

Comment: Cool! You seriously did a big help. :D

Answer (score 2):

I listen the song now. The lyrics are not in Russian. They are in Hindi.

Here you have the English translation: https://www.filmyquotes.com/songs/2955

And Malayalam Translation from here: https://songlyricspro.in/malayalam/

Comment: I do know that it's an Indian song. But it starts with a lady singing song in Russian language and that lyrics are not mentioned anywhere in the internet. It comes after keywords 'lights..' and before 'I'll do the talking tonight'.

Comment: @HarshvardhanSharma I've listen to the song and those lyrics don't sound like Russian to me either.

Comment: @Arsak forget about it being russian. just listen to the song and listen to what the lady sings and tell us about it if you know

Answer (score 1):

The lines you are looking for have been taken from this old song

listen the lines from 0:26

1. Aj, ruse kose, curo, imaš,
   žališ li gi ti?

> 2. Aman, da gi žalim, ne bi' ti gi dala da gi mrsiš ti.

Meaning -----------

1. Hey, blond hairs you have, girl,
   Aren't you sorry for them?

> 2. Aman, if I was sorry, I would never let you ruffle them.

Only, the second line is used in the song "I'll do the talking" !!

You can also read the same over here :
https://www.lyricsmint.com/agent-vinod/i-ll-do-the-talking

[image]

Also listen to the another song mentioned in the pic above, you'll be amazed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys, the song is not Indian, nor is it Russian and neither Serbian. It is a very old Sephardic song and it was brought to Balkans by Sephards (Spanish Jews) as early as 16th century. Original words are in Sephardic language called Ladin and peoples of Balkan just added lyrics in their own languages. Another very old Sephardic tune is known as "Kad ja pođoh na Bembašu"

Comment: Can you add a source for this information? Maybe a recording of the original Sephardic tune?